Symmetry Intuition for Dice Probability Question
My question is a follow-up to this question: Is this a fair game (three players throw dice)?
Player A tosses three six-sided fair dice, and B tosses a fair D-20. Whoever has the larger number/sum of numbers show up is the winner. I want to understand how some people can intuit that this is a symmetrical game. I'm trying to practice my ability to spot symmetry arguments in the wild.
I see a hint of a symmetrical structure in this game, in the following sense:
Let $p_i=P($player A gets a sum $i)$
$P(A>B)=p_3 \frac{2}{20} + p_4 \frac{3}{20} + ... + p_{17} \frac{16}{20} + p_{18} \frac{17}{20}$
$P(A<B)=p_3 \frac{17}{20} + p_4 \frac{16}{20} + ... + p_{17} \frac{3}{20} + p_{18} \frac{2}{20}$
From here, is there a way to intuit that these two probabilities are the same? To me, the only reason these would be the same is if $p_3 = p_{18}, p_4 = p_{17}$ and so on. If they are not the same, then we can see that
$P(A>B) - P(A<B) = \frac{1}{20}(p_{11} - p_{10}) + \frac{3}{20}(p_{12} - p_{9}) + ... + \frac{15}{20}(p_{18} - p_{3})$

The symmetry is that both players have a mean score of $10.5$ and a score distribution that is symmetric around that mean. Thus, for any outcome $(a, b)$, there is another outcome $(21-a, 21-b)$ such that $P(a, b) = P(21-a, 21-b)$. Since the two outcomes have opposite winners, the game is symmetric.

That the three d$6$'s are symmetric in total can be seen by relabeling each side with its opposite number. Thus $P(a = 3) = P(a = 18), P(a = 4) = P(a = 17), \ldots$.

Here's an intuitive interpretation. On a standard $n$-sided die, the numbers $k$ and $n+1-k$ are on opposite faces. For instance, on a $6$-sided die, the opposite-face pairs are $(1,6)$, $(2,5)$, and $(3,4)$.
The intuition is: if player A wins, then if we flip the dice upside down, player B would win (and vice versa). This is because for both players, the "flip upside down" turns a score of $s$ into $21-s$. (For B, it's because $20+1 = 21$. For A, it's because $(6+1)\times 3 = 21$.)
This is an example of a coupling argument. Instead of just considering each random process individually, we "couple" them by, roughly speaking, generating both processes from the same underlying randomness. In this case, we couple together two copies of the same type of process, namely a game between A and B. Both "roll then read the top faces" and "roll then read the bottom faces" are valid ways to generate an instance of the process. But imagining generating both from the same die rolls makes clear that each of A and B has the same chance to win.
